# saber antigüedad de cliente

Tags: sql, sql-server

cordial saludo, 
solicito de su colaboración orientar la necesidad que describo, tengo un listado de cliente y requiero saber si en cada mes un clientes es nuevo o no, es decir, si él un cliente (dbo.OINV.CardCode), está en el mes anterior, de ser así colocar una marca "FIDELIZADO", sino (no esa en el mes anterior) colocar una marca "NUEVO"
 
He realizado la siguiente vista, que me permite saber cuantas facturas por mes tiene el cliente

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
Count(SUBSTRING (dbo.OINV.CardCode, 3,10)) AS Cantdoc,  -- cuento cuantos registros tiene cada tercero por mes
SUBSTRING (dbo.OINV.CardCode, 3,10) AS idcliente,
CONVERT (
        VARCHAR(7),
        dbo.OINV.DocDate,
        120) AS FDoc,
DATENAME("MM", dbo.OINV.DocDate) AS NOMBREMES
 
FROM
dbo.OINV
INNER JOIN dbo.OACT ON dbo.OACT.AcctCode = dbo.OINV.CtlAccount
WHERE
dbo.OINV.DocDate >= '2018-01-01' 
GROUP BY
dbo.OINV.CardCode,
CONVERT (
        VARCHAR(7),
        dbo.OINV.DocDate,
        120),
DATENAME("MM", dbo.OINV.DocDate)
ORDER BY
 dbo.OINV.CardCode, FDoc ASC
```

Lo que me devuelve

```
Cantdoc        idcliente        Fdoc     Mes
1        15985344        2018-03            Marzo
1        24320315        2018-04            Abril
1        30396226        2018-08          Agosto
1        30396226        2018-09          Septiembre
1        800039996        2018-01          Enero
1        800039996        2018-02         Febrero
1        800039996        2018-03         Marzo
```

por favor me guian como puedo complementar para que el resultado sea

```
Cantdoc        idcliente        Fdoc     Marca
1        15985344        2018-03             NUEVO
1        24320315        2018-04             NUEVO
1        30396226        2018-08           NUEVO
1        30396226        2018-09          FIDELIZADO
1        800039996        2018-01          NUEVO
1        800039996        2018-02          FIDELIZADO
1        800039996        2018-03          FIDELIZADO
```

Comment: qué pasa si el cliente existe en un mes previo, pero no el inmediato anterior?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar la estructura de dbo.OINV.CardCode y dbo.OACT?

Comment: No entiendo la condición para que sea NUEVO o FIDELIZADO. Los ejemplos que has puesto no me concuerdan con lo que explicas ¿Puedes explicarlo mejor?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a sustituir esto:

```
DATENAME("MM", dbo.OINV.DocDate) AS NOMBREMES
```

por esto:

```
IF ((SELECT MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())-(MONTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),dbo.OINV.DocDate,120))))>1, "NUEVO", "FIDELIZADO") AS MARCA;
```

Y nos cuentas si es lo que estas buscando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la colaboración. me funciono totalmente